# Firefox Extension - New Tab - How To Override Preferences?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am new to Firefox extension, that is why I use the Add On SDK.

I want to create an extension that shows a specific site every time the user opens up a new tab. This is my code so far:

```js
var self = require("sdk/self");
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

// Listen for tab openings.
tabs.on('open', function onOpen(tab) {
   getActiveTab();
});

function getActiveTab(){
tabs.on('activate', function (tab) {
  tab.url = "http://www.example.com";
});
}
```

This works. But before it loads the specified domain it loads the Firefox default newtab page. Now is there an API reference to access the newtab setting and change to example.com?

Thanks,

Gerd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was possible to change `about:newtab` URL using SDK:

```
require('sdk/preferences/service').set('browser.newtab.url', 'http://www.stackoverflow.com');
```

but it becomes ***obsolete with FF41***, as there isn't a `browser.newtab.url` preference any more.

---

If you still plan on using it, you might also consider adding this to your code:

```
var { when: unload } = require('sdk/system/unload');
var reason;
unload( function ( reason ) {
  require('sdk/preferences/service').set('browser.newtab.url', 'about:newtab');
});
```

so that ***the preference change gets undone after add-on unload***. You can also pass one of unload reasons to the function: `'uninstall'`, `'disable'`, `'shutdown'`, `'upgrade'`, or `'downgrade'`, or not provide `reason` argument at all / leave it undefined.

Comment: Yea I'm curious to see a solution on how to do this now. I tried my hand at it using http observers but it didnt work: https://discourse.mozilla-community.org/t/set-browser-home-page-using-add-on/4161/2?u=noitidart

Comment: @gerdtf and Sagi please see Sebastian's answer below it is correct way for future versions of Fx.

Answer (score 2):

Since the `browser.newtab.url` preference has been removed, this is the new way to do this: https://github.com/sblask/firefox-open-tabs-next-to-current/blob/master/lib/helpers.js#L50 The code of the module can be found here: https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/modules/NewTabURL.jsm

If you also want to replace the homepage, you have to change the `browser.startup.homepage` preference.

Comment: This is the correct way, for example code we can see here: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/files/browse/325220/file/index.js#top `NewTabURL.override(preferences.prefs['url'] || 'about:newtab');`